# Java Recursion and super prime numbers

Tags: java, recursion, primes

This method is intended to recursively go through the method and tell if a number is "super Prime". A super prime number is a number that is prime itself and each time it is diveded by 10 all of those numbers are prime as well. for example 2333 is super prime because 233 is prime 23 is prime and 2 is prime.
My method keeps returning false even though i pass in the number 2333.
the isPrime() method successfully tests if a number is prime.

```
public boolean isSuperPrime(int h)
{
    if((h<10)&&isPrime(h))
        return true;
    else if(isPrime(h))
        return isSuperPrime(h/10);  
    else
        return false;


}
```

Comment: show us your `isPrime()` method.

Comment: Have you run step-by-step under debugger to see how your code works?

Comment: no they're not. It sounds like you came up with the term without checking whether it's already an established name in mathematics. It is -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-prime

Comment: Your isSuperPrime method is correct. The error must be in isPrime.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ... but see the talk page for that article. How established is the name? I had never heard the term "super prime" for either concept.

Comment: even if it's not fully established, it's reason enough to give this a different name, like `isDecimalFactorPrime`.

Comment: You should probably show us your `isPrime()` method. At the very least, have you checked that it returns `true` for 2333, 233, 23 and 2?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your `isPrime` method is incorrect, I ran this exact code:

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
   System.out.println(isSuperPrime(2333));
}

public static boolean isSuperPrime(int h)
{
    if ((h<10)&&isPrime(h))
        return true;
    else if (isPrime(h))
        return isSuperPrime(h/10);  
    else
        return false;
}

//Note this is not an efficient implementation, 
//but it is correct, was just using it to test
public static boolean isPrime(int n)
{
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++) {
        if(n%i==0)
             return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and it returns `true`.

Comment: @TerryLi: Technically you only need to loop to `sqrt(n)`.  Another common optimization is to only check for divisibility by 2 + the odd numbers.

Comment: I realize it is not efficient, it was just the first result when I googled (and is irrelevant to the question just needed something to test with).

Comment: @Terry Even better if you do it to `sqrt(n)` which could be expressed as  `i*i < n` if sqrt takes time.

Comment: @PM77-1: the `isSuperPrime()` function could be more efficient by only calling `isPrime(h)` once, but it **is** correct.  You are wrong - see the comments to your answer.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Absolutely, thanks for the catch-up.

Comment: @PM77-1 True. Advice taken :)

Comment: If using additional memory is allowed, one could store prime numbers already found in some collection and divide only by them.